# Toolbar - Light Title and Light menu

Tags: android, styles, android-appcompat

I am currently working on an application that implements the Appcompat Toolbar.
Now my problem is that if I choose a Light Actionbar as base, the Menu is white and the title is black.
I want both to be white.
If I change to Dark Actionbar as base, the Text is white, but the menu goes dark.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I just want the title text color to be white.

Here's my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>


</resources>
```

And here's the toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

I hope You can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17):

Add this to your toolbar element

```
<!-- dark toolbar -->
<item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
<!-- light popup -->
<item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
```

Comment: You are my hero :D

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add below style in your style.xml for choosing which ever color you want, please change color as per your requirements :

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Used to for the title of the Toolbar -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to for the title of the Toolbar when parent is Theme.AppCompat.Light -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to color the text of the action menu icons -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to color the overflow menu icon -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
    <!-- Color of the Toolbar -->
    <item name="android:background">#455a64</item>
</style>
```

And make sure to add this property to your toolbar :

```
app:theme="@style/MyToolbarStyle"
```

Comment: Thanks. I set gray color for `android:textColorSecondary` (for elements like arrow, settings). Also changed `parent` to "AppTheme" and then a white color became gray, as I wanted.